# Setting up include file dependencies for opencv in a visual studio project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cuda

I am trying to include the code for opencv in a Visual Studio 2013 project. From what I can tell I am doing exactly as I should be but the IDE does not seem to recognize the `#include`.

Here is a picture of the project properties and corresponding file location
[image]

And the corresponding errors
[image]

Comment: set your "Additional include folders" to "opencv/build/include"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer the Link.Header files not correctly setup in your code.You should add base directory.that is should add "opencv/include","opencv/include/opencv","opencv/include/opencv2" base directory in compiler setting.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html

Comment: That link looks perfect at first view, i will try it later. Thank you.